# A python background process (= child of rsyslog process) ... only write on close

Tags: python, linux, shell, rsyslog

Below is a simple python program that logs rsyslog data via StdIn to *py.output.txt*.
My issue is that is doesn't log the data from STDin in **realtime** to the output.

If *ishome.py* runs as a background child process (of rsyslog) ... **no output** is send to  *py.output.txt*
Only when i stop master process .. *py.output.txt* receives the output

#### When  BackGround Process

When i terminate rsyslog it send an EOF to his childprocess *ishome.py* .. and that might trigger the actual write out of the data.

#### When  ForeGround Process

However when i run *ishome.py* as a foreground process *py.output.txt* gets updated in realtime forever new entry. I do not need to close *ishome.py* to write out on every new event.

#### Bash Output

```
>>ps 
root      4328     1  0 21:04 ?  00:00:00   /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
root      4360  4328  1 21:04 ?  00:00:00     python/home/pi/script/ishome.py

>>pi@rasp ~/script $ cat py.output.txt

>>pi@rasp ~/script $ sudo service rsyslog stop
[ ok ] Stopping enhanced syslogd: rsyslogd.
>>pi@rasp ~/script $ cat py.output.txt

 2016-01-24 21:05:32.112457 :2016-01-24T22:04:22+00:00 192.168.0.198 
 2016-01-24 21:05:32.113029 :2016-01-24T22:04:33+00:00 192.168.0.198
```

#### ishome.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from datetime import datetime

filename = open("/home/pi/script/py.output.txt",'a',0)
sys.stdout = filename 

for line in sys.stdin:
    print (str(datetime.now())+' :'+line)
```

First is believed that StdIn was buffered and that the stream was processed at closure. However when i look at the time when a StdIn line was processed, i clearly see that StdIn is processed in realtime. Only the write out is .. not-happening ?

I've tested this scenario with a hundreds of input lines that are written to a MongoDB via PyMongo . Again the db is updated when process is termated.

Any idea's what is causing this delay in writing, i would like to have every new event, been written in realtime to my output (be it DB or a file).

Comment: Try flushing the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Some how sys.strin.readline() would constantly return and empty string, i presume a string with just "/n"

So i added a check in my code .. to solve this issue. case Closed :-)

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line != "":
        result = db.mac.insert_one({"adres":line}) ## My action
```